# Why does indexOf work different when using as is vs comparing it to -1?

Tags: javascript, indexof

Can't seem to find an answer probably due to my lack of googling experience and the mozilla page of indexOf doesn't seem to answer it

```js
//this returns -1 because it can't find 'ca' within cat
var randomArr = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'cheetah'];
console.log(randomArr.indexOf('ca'));

//this returns 1 which is correct, but why?
var randomArr = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'cheetah'];
for (var i = 0; i < randomArr.length; i++) {
  if (randomArr[i].indexOf('ca') !== -1) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

I don't why this works differently when using indexOf. Why does it need an exact string match in one case but not the other?

Comment: Because `"ca"` is contained in `"cat"` but it's not contained in the array. You may expect `indexOf` to unpack and recursively search strings in the array, but it only works one level deep agnostic of whether you're using it on an array or a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, you're calling `.indexOf` on an *array*. This will return the index of the *exact match* of the passed parameter (or -1 if not found).

But when you do

```
randomArr[i].indexOf('ca') !== -1
```

Each item of `randomArr` is a string, so `randomArr[i]` is a string. Calling `randomArr[i].indexOf` invokes `String.prototype.indexOf`, which returns the index of the substring in the string being searched (or -1 if not found).

Since `'cat'` has `'ca'` as a substring, the index of the `c` in `cat` is returned (which is 0).

The methods have the same name, but they're very different.

Comment: Nvm. Got it! Makes total sense. I didn't know it treated each index as a string then searched for the substring where as in the array it's comparing string to string rather than substring which means it has to be an exact match for indexOf using on an array